# Is it more secure to develop libraries in-house than using existing libraries?

Tags: architecture, c++, security, sockets

I (unfortunately) work in a large German corporation, in a department where the codebase is up to 20 years old, written in C++ (actually more like C with the occasional classes, since most developers used to be electrical engineers).
We have a requirement to adhere to certain security standards (which ones exactly I am not told).
This includes creating a new process to which the current process will connect to via TLS and make requests, so essentially a local server. Except the server can also send requests to the client, and there are also asynchronous notifications being sent.
We cannot use any existing libraries due to security concerns (with a few exceptions), so we use plain old Unix sockets and OpenSSL.
Also we use an in-house database system to store users, groups and associated rights.
I found out the DB stores everything in a single json file.
Also we have a software architect who is obsessed with encrypting everything, like there is a SecureString class which given a string encrypts it and stores that in a member variable.
The class is basically a subset of std::string, which stores the string in an encrypted manner.

Now the thing is I am still relatively early in my career and lack some experience, but a lot of this sounds wrong. I am just second guessing myself and wondering if I am the crazy one here, and the described stuff is actually sane.

Comment: It could make perfect sense for a number of reasons but it is hard to tell whether it does because we know nothing about the company in question, its product(s), its people, its history or the constraints they have to work with.

Comment: All this sounds like you are working in an environment with strong security requirements. Nothing sounds wrong here. The fact that you have an old code base is perhaps unfortunate, but restarting from scratch is often not a real option (except in our wildest dreams). Probably you work on industrial systems or critical infrastructure. Take the opportunity to learn. Embrace cryptography and multilayered security. Ask for the why's. See if there's  opportunity to refactor some parts, bit by bit, incrementally. If after a while you're fed-up you can always look for more interesting opportunities.

Comment: Btw. The secure string is a symptom of deep security. If well done, the code would also take the care to overwrite the cleartext version (including in buffers or temporary variables that we do normally not care about). The first time I've see this was in Schneier's PasswordSafe source code. For those who don't know, Schneier is the author of several (long undefeated) cryptographic algorithms (one of which was in the short list for becoming AES standard of US-Gov, so clearly a guy working with world's top experts in the field and knowing a lot about practical security risks).

Comment: Example of standard requiring separate process, for transportation devices: https://www.arc-it.net/html/security/control45.htm

Answer (score 2):

Encryption is most commonly defeated not by cracking it, but by going around it. Misconfigured or poorly implemented encryption solutions will defeat even the latest snazziest security schemes.

Given that I hesitate to recommend rolling your own. Existing solutions are not only tested and reviewed, they are explained well. That last part is most important because it's all to easy to think it's set up correctly when it's not.

Now that said, using typical security measures means you need to be ready for [typical attacks](https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K59197053#:%7E:text=This%20vulnerability%20allows%20a%20remote,1.3%20has%20been%20explicitly%20enabled.) and [problems](https://blog.gigamon.com/2019/07/25/tls-1-3-its-benefits-are-real-but-so-are-the-drawbacks/#:%7E:text=Yet%20TLS%201.3%20is%20a,spots%20for%20security%20analysis%20tools.). The benefit of being typical is you aren't alone in dealing with them.